# JQuery Mobile - how to set up a loading page before website loads

Tags: jquery, jsp, web-applications, jquery-mobile, pageload

I have a `FirstPage.html` on my website.

While the website loads (`FirstPage.html` loads), i want to display a `WelcomePage.html` for at least 5 seconds (even if the `FirstPage.html` finished loading).

Can anybody please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make WelcomePage.html the actual homepage, and then add FirstPage.html to the jquery mobile DOM in the background. Then, redirect to FirstPage.html after X seconds, or after the page finishes loading into the DOM.

Here's the docs: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-cache.html

**Update**

Using the 
Ink I gave you, you need to add the following code in a separate JS file.

```
$.mobile.loadPage( FirstPage.html, { showLoadMsg: false } );
```

You need to include this JS file in the head of WelcomePage.html, AFTER you include jQuery, but BEFORE you include jQuery mobile.

This will load FirstPage.html into the DOM. Then call your other code (I think)

Comment: I made a WelcomePage.html
I've added this code:

http://pastebin.com/MLxb7nUw

Will this do the work? or should i change something?

Comment: Hi Adam

My previous post worked fine according to your link.

Thanks :)